# Problem loading INPUT fields from HTML file in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Problem loading INPUT fields in HTML form in IE.
I upload aspx form,
The form is fully loaded, including the content I submitted to the fields.
At this point everything is fine in chrome,
But in IE and Edge the fields that contain content are unmarkable. It is only after about two minutes that the fields are allowed to select and mark the text.
My client copies information from this form, so the fields should be open for text markup and copying.
Does anyone have an idea why they don't open immediately and how to solve it?

when i debuging  the code, everything seems to load properly.
In the Network tab of IE Developer Tools, Everything seems to end up charging pretty quickly.
What else should I check?

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I replaced one field of type "text" to type "textarea".
It seems to have enabled the page to load properly in IE.
Does anyone know how to explain this phenomenon?

Previous Code:

```
     <div>
        <div>
            <label>first name</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="1" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled />

        </div>

        <div>
            <label >last name</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="2" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="3" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Locality</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="4" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
```

New Code:

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>first name</label>
            <div style="overflow: hidden; background-color:#eee; padding:0;" ><textarea style="width: 120%;border:none;box-shadow:none;"  rows="1" tabindex="1" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled></textarea></div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label >last name</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="2" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
         <div>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="3" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Locality</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="4" maxlength="50" data-fv-notempty="true" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
```